# Is being in the Sobolev space of power $\frac{d}{2}$ necessary for having well defined point evaluations?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, fractional-sobolev-spaces

From the Sobolev embedding theorem we know that for $\alpha = \frac{d}{2}$,  $W^{\alpha, 2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is continuously embedded in $C^0(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Especially the point evaluations are in the dual of $W^{\alpha, 2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and thus well defined.

But is it also necessary to be in $W^{\alpha, 2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to have well-defined point evaluations? Or is there maybe some $\beta < \alpha = \frac{d}{2}$ s.t. the point evaluations are well defined functions on $W^{\beta, 2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ even if they aren't continuous anymore.

**Edit:** By well-definedness I mean that if there is a $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ s.t. $f(x) \not= g(x)$ for two representants of functions $f, g \in W^{\beta, 2}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ then $||f-g||_\beta \not= 0$ (they do not have the same equivalence class)

Comment: Denoting by $C^0_0(R^d)$ the continuous functions vanishing at infinity, then point evaluation are a continuous functional on this space, with the uniform norm. However, not all functions in $C^0_0(R^d)$ are in L2. So Sobolev regularity is not necessary.